# Convert list of dict to lists using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb, list, dictionary

Have two lists with values :

```
[{'_id': ObjectId('5ab123e123c075f123ec11ab'),
  'stp_id': ObjectId('5ab000c12345ac9d12345678'),
  'date': Timestamp('2019-11-01 05:38:44.089000')}]
```

```
[{'_id': ObjectId('5ab123e123c075f123ec11ad'),
  'stp_id': ObjectId('5ab000c12345ac9d12345679'),
  'date': Timestamp('2019-10-01 05:38:44.089000')},
{'_id': ObjectId('5ab123e123c075f123ec11ac'),
  'stp_id': ObjectId('5ab000c12345ac9d12345679'),
  'date': Timestamp('2019-10-01 05:38:44.089000')}]
```

how to convert these list of dicts to dicts like this :

```
{{'_id': ObjectId('5ab123e123c075f123ec11ab'),
  'stp_id': ObjectId('5ab000c12345ac9d12345678'),
  'date': Timestamp('2019-11-01 05:38:44.089000')}}
```

```
{{'_id': ObjectId('5ab123e123c075f123ec11ad'),
  'stp_id': ObjectId('5ab000c12345ac9d12345679'),
  'date': Timestamp('2019-10-01 05:38:44.089000')},
{'_id': ObjectId('5ab123e123c075f123ec11ac'),
  'stp_id': ObjectId('5ab000c12345ac9d12345679'),
  'date': Timestamp('2019-10-01 05:38:44.089000')}}
```

Comment: What is the key for those nested dicts? This is not valid python

Comment: A `dict` is pairs of keys and values. in you're second format what are the keys exactly?

Comment: for pushing them into mongodb using pymongo.  i'm getting error response while pushong an array. So trying yo push the dictionary

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert a list into dict following approach can be used,

```
l1=[{"id":1,"stp_id":2,"date":3}]

d1=dict()

d1["l1"]=l1

print(d1)
```

output:

```
{'l1': [{'id': 1, 'stp_id': 2, 'date': 3}]}
```

as per this approach you can add multiple lists into one dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

```
{{'_id': ObjectId('5ab123e123c075f123ec11ad'),
  'stp_id': ObjectId('5ab000c12345ac9d12345679'),
  'date': Timestamp('2019-10-01 05:38:44.089000')},
{'_id': ObjectId('5ab123e123c075f123ec11ac'),
  'stp_id': ObjectId('5ab000c12345ac9d12345679'),
  'date': Timestamp('2019-10-01 05:38:44.089000')}}
```

is not a `dict` because a `dict` needs to have a `key` and a `value`

But you can instead individual dictionaries from the list of dictionaaries

Try this:

```
li = [{'_id': ObjectId('5ab123e123c075f123ec11ad'),
       'stp_id': ObjectId('5ab000c12345ac9d12345679'),
       'date': Timestamp('2019-10-01 05:38:44.089000')},
      {'_id': ObjectId('5ab123e123c075f123ec11ac'),
       'stp_id': ObjectId('5ab000c12345ac9d12345679'),
       'date': Timestamp('2019-10-01 05:38:44.089000')}]

for x in li:
    print(dict(x))
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use dict.values() within a list comprehension to get the values and then use zip in order to get the columns :

> [list(col) for col in zip(*[d.values() for d in myList])]

[[0, 1], [2, 3]]